# Storing k-ary tree with an array

Tags: arrays, data-structures, tree

Does storing a k-ary tree as an array only work if you fill in each node from left to right with k-children before moving to the next one?

Ex:

```
        1
      / | \
    2   3   4
  / | \
 5  6  7
```

Can be stored as an array that looks like:

```
[X,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

And any parent can be found by taking the index/k.

However, for the same data but stored as:

```
        1
      / | \
    2   3   4
  / |   |
 5  6   7
```

with 7 as a child of 3 indexing no longer works.

Also, in general, the siblings are within +- k indices of the current node but how do I make sure I'm not accidentally accessing a parent/uncle node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the root node is at index 0 in the array, then the children of the node at index `i` are at indexes `(i*n) + 1` through `(i*n) + n`. A node's parent is at index `(i-1)/n`. There are similar equations for if you want to put the root at index 1, but there's no good reason to leave index 0 unoccupied.

If you want to visit all of the siblings of the current node, first find the parent node, and then visit all of that node's children. That way you won't accidentally visit an "uncle" node.

Normally, trees stored in an array like this are complete binary trees: all levels except possibly the last are full, and if the last level isn't completely full, then it's filled from left to right.

You don't have to fill in all positions, but if you don't then you need to have some kind of flag at that node's position to tell you that it's empty.

But storing the tree as in your second example, where the first child of index 3 is where one would normally put the last child of index 2 breaks those calculations. You would have to store an array of child indexes in the parent node, and the index of the parent in each child node.